# Which version of Tweak Tool suitable for 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-tweak

Which version of unity tweek tool for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS . I've tried GNOME tweek tool.deb it said `Dependency is not satisfiable: gnome-shell-common(=>3.4 )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its Unity Tweak Tool 0.0.6 version and it will be available in software center.

Comment: You can also download unity-tweak-tool from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/unity-tweak-tool), and gnome-tweak-tool from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gnome-tweak-tool)